# How to call different images with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am creating an industry section, like the one seen in https://squareup.com

I started using nth-of-type to call different images in the css. http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/vinttbws

However, it doesn't work when they are not all in the same parent. How can I get that to work?

Is there another way to accomplish this without having to make a div class for each industry with an image?

Comment: Add your html so we can see whats going on

Answer (score 1):

You're right, `nth-of-type` won't work because they don't share the same immediate parent.

I would highly recommend that you do what you were suggesting with making a new class for each one.

You could also give each parent a different id and then your css selector would just ask for the child:

```
#restaurant > a {
  background-image:url(some/picture.jpg);
}

#retail > a {
  background-image:url(some/other/picture.jpg);
}
```

I've made a bit of an example here(with colors instead of pictures): http://jsfiddle.net/mo9yazjm/

Edit: I made the change now to your CSSDeck example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/t4xnpzgf

Answer (score 1):

You can do either with **adding different CSS class** to the HTML markup, or use only **CSS3** *nth type* selector.
The first method is more verbose, because you have to modify and update your markup consistently with CSS. The latter is best in the matter of consistently and maintenance because you operate only on CSS.

### CSS Class on Markup

#### HTML

```
<div class="some-class"><a href="#">Restaurant</a></div>
<div class="other-class"><a href="#">Retail</a></div>
<div class="some-other-class"><a href="#">Gym</a></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.some-class a       {background-color: red;}
.other-class a      {background-color: gold;}
.some-other-class a {background-color: aqua;}
```

Here is the [live example](http://jsbin.com/jipixiqaki/1/edit?html,css,output).

### CSS3 Only

Try add the style to the `div` with [`nth-of-type` CSS3 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), and apply the style to the *anchor*:

```
.col-md-4:nth-of-type(1) a {
  background-color: red;
 }
```

[Here is the working link](http://jsbin.com/cigigajize/1/edit?html,css,output). I use the background-color, you can use the background-image, or whaterver your layout need.

Comment: Selecting on the class .col-md-4 is dangerous since there could be other 4-column divs in the page that contain multiple links. Remember that the first a tag in *each* of those will have a red background as well with this code, which may be unwatned.

Comment: Yes, but you can be more specific, selecting the column you need by its parent class, as for example: ".PARENT-CLASS col-md-4:nth-of-type(1)"

Comment: Mark my answer as the correct for you, flagging it with the red flag, so it close the question. :-)

Comment: Now, would you say this is a good solution for a commercial website? Would i run into too many cross-browser issues?

Comment: Follow the link in my answer and check the compatibility fot the CSS3 nth-type. It is pretty wide supported in browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 http://i61.tinypic.com/29p4zea.jpg But, my advice, always test your code in many browser as you could.

Comment: @AndreaCarolinaAvellan i've updated my reply with a CSS2 solution, for better cross browser compatibility. It's good for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nth-of-type on the parent (.col-md-4:nth-of-type(1), etc)

Answer (score -1):

*:nth-of-type* applies to child elements of the **same** parent, while you have your pictures in separate *div*s. You'll want something like this:

```
     <div>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
     </div>
```